# How to upgrade gnuradio 3.7.5 to above?

Tags: gnuradio

I want to upgrade gnuradio companion but I do not know any command any one who know please help me?

Comment: Why do you want a newer version of the software? Do you need to use a feature that was added or does it fix a bug for you? Otherwise just leave it the way it is. You can always upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release. Wily has gnuradio 3.7.8 currently.

Comment: because of some modules or files supported in a newer version

Answer (score 1):

You can build it from sources, of cource, or install via PyBombs. I like the way with PyBombs. You got a most newer version, but i recommend to REMOVE currently installed via apt-get version of gnu-radio:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnuradio* libgnuradio-*
```

Do not forget to remove the libraries that depends on gnuradio. If something goes wrong, you can always install them back :)

First, install pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Next: PyBombs

```
sudo pip install PyBOMBS
sudo pybombs prefix init /usr/local -a default_prx
sudo pybombs config default_prefix default_prx
sudo pybombs recipes add gr-recipes git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-recipes.git
sudo pybombs recipes add gr-etcetera git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-etcetera.git
```

Next, install gnuradio:

```
sudo pybombs install gnuradio
```

If you are like to use beautiful gr-fosphor, install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev ocl-icd-opencl-dev libqt4-opengl-dev
sudo pybombs install gr-fosphor
```

Thats it, we are done!

PS: to avoid some possible errors, check if you gcc-compiler version are >= 5, but not => 6